# How to join db value as string with comma separator using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to join DB value as string with comma(`,`) separator using PHP and Mysql.I am explaining my table below.

> db_order:

```
id         name

1           Rahul

2           Raj


3           Shiv

4          Hari


$qry=mysqli_query($con,"select * from db_order");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
   $data[]=$row;
}
print_r($data);
```

From my table i need to join all name with comma(`,`) so that result should like this `Rahul,Raj,Shiv,Hari` by executing the query.Please help me.

Comment: Do you already have tried to solve it yourself? You got to have at least some code, right?

Comment: i can only fetch the name using query but little bit confused how to join finaly with comma.

Comment: Then you should at least show your code till the point when you fetch the results of the query

Comment: Search: **explode()** function in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use php then it will be like

```
$qry = mysqli_query($con,"select * from db_order");
$str = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
   $str .= $row['name'].",";
}
$data = rtrim($str, ",");
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
SELECT group_concat(name separator ',') FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get values from ur query by comma separated.

If you are using mysql, then you can get name of table comma separated like

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(name) from <table_name>;
```

and if you have database in oracle then u can use wm_concat() in place of GROUP_CONCAT().

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'test';

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die("Error:" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Unable to select DB" . mysql_error());

$qry = "SELECT id, name FROM users";

$res = mysql_query($qry, $con) or die("Error to execute query " . mysql_error());

$users = '';
if (mysql_num_rows($res)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        if ($users) {
            $users .= ',' . $row['name'];
        } else {
            $users = $row['name'];
        }
    }
}

echo $users;
```